# Searching in posts db fields

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a search function that searches the posts columns in the database

```
  def self.search(query)
    where("text like ?", "%#{query}%") 
  end
```

So this searches post.text. However I want to search through post.text and post.title for the specific keyword given.

I tried something like this:

```
  def self.search(query)
    where("text like ?", "%#{query}%" OR "title like ?", "%#{query}%") 
  end
```

but it doesn't work. Any clues?

Comment: What version of rails?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: https://coderwall.com/p/dgv7ag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct it manually or use a 3rd party plugin. but the below should work

```
def self.search(query)
  where("text like :query OR title like :query", :query => "%#{query}%")
end
```

Comment: does this makes sure that the query is safe from sql injection? normally i'd use where('text like %?% OR title like %?%', query, query)

Comment: @Marc-AlexandreBérubé yes it does.